# pandas: pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have the following code operating on data frame `df`:

```
  print df
  categories = df['my_classification'].unique()
  for c in categories:
    print c
    win = df[df.result == 'Won'][df['my_classification'] == c]['prob'][0]

    print type(win)
    lost = df[df.result == 'Lost'][df['my_classification'] == c]['prob'][0]
    print type(lost)
```

Then I got the following output:

```
   result          my_classification      prob
0  Won                   ENTERPRISE      0.657895
1  Won                   COMMERCIAL      0.342105
2  Lost                  ENTERPRISE      0.611842
3  Lost                  COMMERCIAL      0.388158
ENTERPRISE
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

And the errors:

```
There was a problem running this cell
KeyError 0 
KeyErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-38a901f9868a> in <module>()
     38 
     39     print type(win)
---> 40     lost = df[df.result == 'Lost'][df['my_classification'] == c]['prob'][0]
     41 
     42     print type(lost)

/opt/conda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    599         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    600         try:
--> 601             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    602 
    603             if not is_scalar(result):

/opt/conda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
   2426         try:
   2427             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2428                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   2429         except KeyError as e1:
   2430             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/_libs/index.c:4363)()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/_libs/index.c:4046)()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5085)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:13913)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:13857)()

KeyError: 0
```

Here is what I don't understand: win and lost are of exactly the same format, why `win` was ok but `lost` generated an error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cause you get the `categories` from whole dataframe, but for won and lost you filter them by the subset , sometime it dose not exist

For example df as follow

```
  result my_classification      prob
0    Won        ENTERPRISE  0.657895
1    Won        COMMERCIAL  0.342105
2   Lost        ENTERPRISE  0.611842
```

when you do

```
df[df.result == 'Lost'][df['my_classification'] == 'COMMERCIAL']['prob'][0]
```

it will return the error

My solution by using `groupby`

```
df.groupby(['result','my_classification']).head(1)
```

Comment: But in my case, the error occurred when there is no missing category in the List group. I also tried: df.groupby(['result','my_classification']).head(1) ... still the same error ...

Comment: I noticed if I replace "df['my_classification'] == c " with df['my_classification'] == 'ENTERPRISE'   the hard coding of the category value makes the error go away ... why is that?